# CSS: aligning text of buttons inside a container

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

Initially, I want to build a single button like this

[image]

I could not figure out how to put them all inside one button, therefore I create two buttons to perform the same functionality inside a same container.

But the text is not aligned vertically as here.

[image]

I tried within-line block and text-align but they just do not work well.

My css is like this:

```
.button_tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(49, 63, 92, 1);
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.button {
  white-space: pre;
  color: rgba(240, 167, 54, 1);
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<span class="button_tab">
  <button class="button">
    Tue
    Jun</button>
  <button class="button">
    24
    </button>  
</span>
```

Any ideas on how to align the buttons and text inside?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

```css
.button_wrapper {
  background-color: #252c3e;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button_tab {
  background-color: #313f5c;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 3em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.button {
  color: rgba(240, 167, 54, 1);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button span:first-child {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.button span:last-child {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_wrapper">
  <div class="button_tab">
    <div class="button">
      <span>
        <b>Tue</b>
        <br>
        Jun
      </span>
      <span>
        24
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is great! But is it possible to do it within one button?

Comment: Well, much appreciated. I actually want a button that can be clicked. I substitute your div into button and fade the background out. It works. Only problem here is there are plenty of space in the Pad that cannot be clicked, but it is a minor issue only, thanks so much for help. Accepted!

Comment: Oh no. I substitute the wrapper div to button, whole thing is clickable. I am too newbie.== Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
.date {
 display: block;
 background: midnightblue;
 color: orange;
 font-family: monospace;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 240px;
 height: calc(90px / 6 * 4);
 padding: calc(90px / 6) 0;
}
.date span {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 width: 40%;
 height: calc(90px / 6 * 2);
 font-size: calc(90px / 6 * 2);
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: right;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
}
.date span span { display: none; }
.date > span:last-child {
 float: right;
 margin: calc(-90px / 6 * 4) 0 0;
 height: calc(90px / 6 * 4);
 font-size: calc(90px / 6 * 4);
 text-align: left;
 width: 50%;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="width: 240px; height: 90px; background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6ioZ.jpg) 50% 50%;"></div>
  <a href="#foo" title="bar" class="date"><span>Tue<span>sday,</span></span> <span>Jun<span>e</span></span> <span>24<span>th</span></span></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<button class="button_tab"  onclick="alert();">
    <div class="button">Tue<br>Jun</div>
    <div class="button day">24</div>
</button>
```

with below css

```
<style>
.button_tab {
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(49, 63, 92, 1);
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  align-items: center;
}
.button {
  white-space: pre;
  color: rgba(240, 167, 54, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}
.day{
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 200%;
}
</style>
```